# awk printing same line over and over

Tags: awk, printing, conditional-statements

rookie looking for help

I have a big file (2000+ rows, 1455 columns)

- I would like to iterate through cells and only print columns/samples that have values <200
- Do I have to transpose my table/array or is there another solution?
- Once it finds value <200 I want it to print and move onto next column (so it doesn't print the same
- I would also like to include my headers

`awk '{for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) if ($i<200) print} {next}'  table.txt`

This is what I'm working with now - but it iterates through rows(?) (starting at column 3 - sample 1) and prints the same row every time it finds a value less than 200 in that row instead of going straight to next row after printing.

`awk '{for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) if ($i<200) print} {next}'  table.txt`

table.txt (small selection)

| Gene | targ_bp | s_1 | s_2 | s_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GNB1 | 217 | 53 | 102 | 1121 |
| GNB1 | 202 | 1112 | 96 | 1226 |
| GNB1 | 163 | 1141 | 1162 | 1181 |

Output with current code:

| GNB1 | 217     | 53   | 102  | 1121 |

| GNB1 | 217     | 53   | 102  | 1121 |

| GNB1 | 202     | 1112 | 96   | 1226 |

Desired:

| Gene | targ_bp | s_1 | s_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GNB1 | 217 | 53 | 102 |
| GNB1 | 202 | 1112 | 96 |

- With header, removed rows where all>200 and columns where all>200.

Hope I am clear enough. 0=)

Comment: You can submit the same file twice to `(g)awk` to make two passes `awk ... SOMEFILE SOMEFILE` and you can tell if you are in the first or second pass like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34162658/2836621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a 2-pass approach to identify the rows and columns that need to be printed in the first pass and then print them in the second pass, e.g. using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS = "\t"
    begInColNr = 3
}
NR == FNR {
    if ( FNR == 1 ) {
        outRowNrs[FNR]
        for ( inColNr=1; inColNr<begInColNr; inColNr++ ) {
            inColNrs[inColNr]
        }
    }
    else {
        for ( inColNr=begInColNr; inColNr<=NF; inColNr++ ) {
            if ( $inColNr < 200 ) {
                outRowNrs[FNR]
                inColNrs[inColNr]
            }
        }
    }
    next
}
FNR in outRowNrs {
    if ( FNR == 1 ) {
        for ( inColNr=1; inColNr<=NF; inColNr++ ) {
            if ( inColNr in inColNrs ) {
                out2inColNrs[++numOutCols] = inColNr
            }
        }
    }
    for ( outColNr=1; outColNr<=numOutCols; outColNr++ ) {
        inColNr = out2inColNrs[outColNr]
        printf "%s%s", $inColNr, (outColNr<numOutCols ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk table.txt table.txt
Gene    targ_bp s_1     s_2
GNB1    217     53      102
GNB1    202     1112    96
```

Comment: Perfect! This worked! Was hoping for a one-liner. But this definitely does the job. Thank you! 
(And sorry for the inconsistency in OP, first time posting a question here, and making tables was harder than expected..) =)

Answer (score 0):

> is there another solution?

You can iterate over the file twice, first to get the columns, and then print the columns. Something along:

```
# generate comma separated list of columns we want to print
columns=$(awk '
    {
       for (i=6; i<=NF; i++)
            # If the column was not handled, and it has value below 200
            if (!(i in cols) && $i<200)
               # Add it as an index in cols variable
               cols[i]=1
    }
    END{ 
         for (i in cols) print i
    }' input.txt |
    # Join columns numbers using comma
    paste -sd,
)
# Output only columns from input.txt.
cut -d$'\t' -f"$columns" input.txt
# If you do not know if it's tab or space, you can squeeze first
tr -s ' \t' '\t' < input.txt | cut -d$'\t' -f"$columns"
```

Comment: That `for (i in cols) print i` will print the columns in a "random" order. You could pipe the awk output to `sort` but best I can tell that approach won't do the "removed rows where all>200" part of the OPs requirements.